# Where should I ask question about installing something on a shared hosting server?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I've asked a question on Server Fault:

*[Install/compile PHP module from source into home directory](https://serverfault.com/questions/942721/install-compile-php-module-from-source-into-home-directory)*

And it was put on hold. I was thinking that this was just the question for Server Fault, but it seems it's not, because it was marked by a moderator.

Where should I ask this question?

Comment: probably Super User

Comment: What do you mean by *"but it seems it now"*?

Comment: @PeterMortensen it was a typo it suppose to be "it's not"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears like your question is on-topic for [Super User](https://stackoverflow.com).

Additionally, reading your question, it seems the environment is a Linux server, so the question may also be suitable on [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com).

I would prefer SU than U&L.

A friendly reminder: don't cross-post (post the same question on more than one site).

Comment: `don't cross-post` even if it's put on Hold and I'll delete it?

Comment: @jcubic If it's put on hold for being off-topic (not suitable on the site), then you may try posting on another site. Otherwise, please don't.